# Создание файла Excel через COM Windows API на Visual Studio C++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, excel, ole, office

Нашел примеры на сайтике фирмы микрософт

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CppAutomateExcel-44214081         
solution 2

Приведен пример как включить эксель, создать worksheet, записать пару имен и сохранить все в файл xlsx.

Все это в следующем виде:

```
VARIANT saNames;
saNames.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;
{
    SAFEARRAYBOUND sab[2];
    sab[0].lLbound = 1; sab[0].cElements = 5;
    sab[1].lLbound = 1; sab[1].cElements = 2;
    saNames.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 2, sab);

    SafeArrayPutName(saNames.parray, 1, L"John", L"Smith");
    SafeArrayPutName(saNames.parray, 2, L"Tom", L"Brown");
    SafeArrayPutName(saNames.parray, 3, L"Sue", L"Thomas");
    SafeArrayPutName(saNames.parray, 4, L"Jane", L"Jones");
    SafeArrayPutName(saNames.parray, 5, L"Adam", L"Johnson");
}

// Fill A2:B6 with the array of values (First and Last Names).

// Get Range object for the Range A2:B6
IDispatch *pXlRange = NULL;
{
    VARIANT param;
    param.vt = VT_BSTR;
    param.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"A2:B6");

    VARIANT result;
    VariantInit(&result);
    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &result, pXlSheet, L"Range", 1, param);
    pXlRange = result.pdispVal;

    VariantClear(&param);
}

{
    IDispatch *pXlCells, *pXlEntireColumn;

    VARIANT result;
    VariantInit(&result);
    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result, pXlSheet,L"Cells", 0);
    pXlCells=result.pdispVal;

    VariantInit(&result);
    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,&result, pXlCells,L"EntireColumn", 0);
    pXlEntireColumn=result.pdispVal;

    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL,pXlEntireColumn,L"ColumnWidth", 1, 50);
}
```

Приведенных в примере функций мне недостаточно. Еще нужно как минимум изменение ширины n-ого столбца, задание цвета текста и центрирование текса в ячейке.

При просмотре интернета, не было обнаружено подробной документации по этим функциям. Где её искать или спросить? Какие аргументы надо передать методу AutoWrap() чтобы задать ширину столбца

Comment: для вас принципиально использовать именно COM и С++?

Comment: Пишу что нужно в порядке важности: 

1)нужно обязательно чтобы оно было консольное.  

2)чтобы запускалось независимо от версии винды и микрософт офиса. 

3)чтобы запускалось без дополнительно устанавливаемых библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)нужно обязательно чтобы оно было консольное.
> 2)чтобы запускалось независимо от версии винды и микрософт офиса.
> 3)чтобы запускалось без дополнительно устанавливаемых библиотек.

тогда вам имеет смысл забыть о COM, поскольку в этом случае будет невозможно выполнить пункты 2 и 3. Насколько мне известно, работа с MS Office через COM требует установленного MS Office и не может выполняться с Office от версии 2007 и выше. Посмотрите в сторону [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) - он куда более удобен, нежели разработка с помощью COM, не требует установленного Office и позволяет создавать и редактировать документы последних версий офиса.

Comment: Есть у вас пример проекта? Или хотябы кусок с записью в эксель?

Comment: у меня нет, в поледний раз занимался этим 2 года назад на предыдущей работе. Но с SDK  поставляется вполне обширная документация с примерами

Comment: Получается что приложение нада писать на си-шарпе ? Можно конечно и на нем, но получается что будет требоваться NET Framework ?

Comment: >но получается что будет требоваться NET Framework ?

скажите, а где его сейчас нет? На компьютерах с версией ОС < WinXP? Не думаю, что это очень уж существенный процент. В любом случае вам придется чем-то жертвовать

Comment: да, вы были абсолютно правы)